# How to fix 795: unexpected token at 'FORBIDDEN'? Rails 4.2.3 and HTTParty + GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I have the following class and controller

```ruby
 class Recipe
  include HTTParty

  hostport = ENV["FOOD2FORK_SERVER_AND_PORT"] || "www.food2fork.com"
  base_uri "http://#{hostport}/api"
  default_params key: ENV["FOOD2FORK_KEY"]
  format :json

  def self.for (keyword)
    request = get("/search", query: { q: keyword })
    begin
      request.inspect
    rescue => e
      puts e.inspect
    end
    return request.parsed_response["recipes"]
  end
end
```

---

```ruby
 class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search_term = params[:search] || "chocolate"
    @recipes_found = Recipe.for(@search_term)
  end
end
```

---

Works fine in console
[image: Rails Console output]

---

JSON::ParserError in RecipesController#index

[image: Browser output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to fix 795: unexpected token at 'FORBIDDEN'?

That means that the key given in the ENV["FOOD2FORK_KEY"] is wrong and you should maybe use puts to check if is not nil.

Comment: I have double checked the key as suggested and it's not nil. What's puzzle me is that I'm able to access data in rails console.

Comment: Post the code of the recipe view, maybe something there is the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but you were right. Environment variables weren't set for my entire user profile. Therefore, it was nil outside my console session.  I have added them to my profile **'.bashrc'** file on ubuntu logged out and logged back in. This time they got initialize properly and I didn't get an error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but if you're following the course, there is some wrong syntax in the Wiki

```
`echo 'export FOOD2FORK_KEY = "Your API Key"' >> ~/.profile`
```

should be

```
`echo 'export FOOD2FORK_KEY="Your API Key"' >> ~/.profile`
```

You made need to edit your ~/.profile and delete those set ENV Vars